# terminal exited when i use "string" type in my code

Tags: c++, string, terminal

```
The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command c:\CodeField\CPP\luogu\bin\a.exe" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

here is my code,no problem with my use of other variables

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        cin>>s;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714), [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: What input did you give your program?

Comment: This code doesn't contain anything what could explain crash. I suspected that you reduced your example to much. Please provide your full code and example of input for which program crashes (for now you do not have enough experience to provide minimal complete reproducible example).